# PendingIntent error ( Must be one or more of: PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT …..)

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I am trying to create a PendingIntent in Android. Here is the code

```
mNotificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContent(), MyAlarm.class);
mContentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                   0, mNotificationIntent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
  Must be one or more of: PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_shot,PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE, 
         PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT, 
         Intent.FILL_IN_ACTION, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA, Intent.FILL_IN_CATEGORIES…..)
```

Why is this error showing ? How to resolve this? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: why? did you read `PendingIntent#getActivity(Context context, int requestCode, Intent intent, int flags)` javadocs?

Comment: @pskink The PendingIntent#getActivity javadoc is unclear: there are two intents involved, each having their own flags (?) , and the javadoc is a bit ambiguous about which intent is to have the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK set .

Answer (score 22):

You are passing `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when the method call expects a `PendingIntent` flag. If you want to add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to your `Intent`, you need to do it like this:

```
mNotificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContent(), MyAlarm.class);
mNotificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mContentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
               0, mNotificationIntent, 0);
```